# DoEvents para permitir edición mientras se aplica un Application.Wait

Tags: excel, vba

Dentro del código desarrollado, es necesario, IF existe un valor en una celda en concreto (AC4) Then Application.Waits durante 3 minutos. El problema es que necesito poder seguir editando en la hoja de excel, lo único que busco es que se detenga la macro durante tres minutos, para luego seguir. Al emplear el DoEvents o bien no lo estoy situando bien, o bien no realiza su trabajo. Adjunto código y gracias:

```
Sub CopiarDatos2()
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tips").Range("C9")
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("Z4").Copy
Sheets("Tips").Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
If Range("AC4") <> "" Then Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Dim HorasOcupadas As Object: Set HorasOcupadas = CargaHorasOcupadas
Dim HoraStr As String
Dim HoraDeseada As Date
HoraDeseada = Range("Z4").Value
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
Dim HoraOcupada As Boolean: HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Do While HoraOcupada
    HoraDeseada = DateAdd("n", 2, HoraDeseada)
    HoraStr = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
    HoraOcupada = HorasOcupadas.Exists(HoraStr)
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1") 'Cambia Hoja1 por la hoja donde tienes los datos
    Dim lrow: lrow = Range("Z4").Row
    .Cells(lrow, "AB").Value = Format(HoraDeseada, "hh:mm")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No veo el do events (supongo lo sacaste), mas alla de eso, el do events va a permitir que se ejecuten eventos de desarrollo (por ejemplo un timer).. no se si excel te dejara hacer esas cosas...

Comment: Si saque el Do.Events, ya que no se donde situarlo, ahora mismo lo que quiero evitar es que se quede colgado con la aplicación del Application.Waits (para que se puedan calcular otros campos o editar celdas). Entonces el Do.Events no es la solución?

Comment: No porque no va a hacer eso que vos queres.. igual si haces wait, se cuelga toda la aplicacion.. para lo que vos queres deberias usar threads.. y no recuerdo si VBA tenia siquiera algo parecido...

Comment: *lo único que busco es que se detenga la macro durante tres minutos*. En `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))` has puesto 10 segundos, no 3 minutos.

Comment: `DoEvents` en sí deja que otros sistemas hagan cosas, pero no te devuelve el control de la macro, deberías abrir un formulario para que te dé el control y seguir editando.

Comment: Como podría realizar eso?

Comment: Una opción es lanzar una primera macro que compruebe el contenido de la celda AC4 y, si no tiene nada, pare. En ese momento lanzas una macro para que cada vez que alguien escriba algo en una celda almacene el tiempo transcurrido desde que paró la primera macro hasta ese momento de edición. Si el momento de edición es superior a los tres minutos lanzas tu segunda macro.

Esa macro que tome tiempos en la edición de la hoja no debería consumir mucho y permitiría, en teoría, hacer lo que buscas. Digo en teoría porque no lo he probado, pero bien montado creo que podría funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, recurriré a esa solución, la verdad que es más sencilla.